# Can you complete The Surge at lvl 10?

Tags: the-surge

I noticed that there are lvl10 overcharge panels even at the end of the game. So I wonder if all lvl11+ overcharges are optional?
Can you (theoretically) complete The Surge at lvl10?

Comment: I can't find any proof, but I've heard from several people that this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can complete the game on core lvl 10. All terminals overrides needed for game completion require lvl 10.

For example, here is [the video](https://youtu.be/197j7fUXUsI) of guy fighting the last boss on lvl 10.